# Update entity framework entity with multiple relationships to other entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-web-api2

I am using web api with entity framework core. I have a Worker entity with relationships to Company (via CompanyId),  Status (via StatusId) and Position (via PositionId). Using a request through the API I want to be able to update a worker.

I want to pass a request of WorkerId and PositionId only. In the data layer I check to find the PositiionId exists from the request, if not the return back to the controller with message of Position not found. Below is a sample of the code without the Company and Status checks.

```
Public void Update(WorkerEntity worker)
{
    var workerRecord = _context.WorkerEntity.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == worker.Id);

    if (workerRecord == null)
    {
         Log.Logger("Cannot find the worker with Id " + worker.Id);
         return;
    }

    var positionRecord = _context.PositionEntity.SingleOrDefault(w => w.Id == worker.PositionId);

    if (positionRecord == null)
    {
         Log.Logger("Cannot find the position with Id " + worker.PositionId);
         return;
    }

    workerRecord.Position = positionRecord;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have also tried a simple approach using **.Single** to catch an error if the record does exist but the catch only output the generic "Sequence contains no elements" which isn't helpful in knowing with entity failed.

Is there an easier way to check the relationship Ids the user has added in the request are not bogus without having lines and code checking the Id exists? This table may have 3 relationships but I have another table that has 5 which would have 5 if null checks.

Comment: Does your ef connection string pointing to correct db? When you use `Single` there must be one record in database according to your query. If there isn't it throw `Sequence contains no elements`, which is correct behavior.

Comment: Entity framework and the context is all setup correctly. I am wanting to know if there is a neater way for this solution. The problem with single is if a user enter a bogus Id in the request then there is no way to know which Id threw the error if I use Single.

Comment: The way you are doing it, it's correct. User `SingleOrDefault` and check for null.

Comment: Well, you have to check each Id against a specific database table. I don't see any shorthand for that. The checks can be made lighter though by using `Any` instead of `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: If you only want to know that is there any record against your query you can use `Any` which will return bool.

Answer (score 0):

To get a meaningful message you would have to check each field manually. It can be simplified little bit using Any() method.

```
if (!context.PositionEntity.Any(w => w.Id == worker.PositionId)
{
    Log.Logger("Cannot find the position with Id " + worker.PositionId);
    return;
}
```

From the EF exception you wont be able to get a descriptive error message.

But you do you really want to do this? I assume you have these lookup values (Positions, statuses etc) as dropdowns in front-end where you load them with values from your database. So in the normal scenario an incorrect value cannot be selected and send to the API. However somehow if it does, you have the EF core default error to avoid screwing up things.

Cheers,